# Change Drobo directory permissions

Tags: ubuntu, usb, file-permissions, drobo

I have a Drobo unit that is connected via fire-wire to a Dell notebook. Using Ubuntu 12.04. I can not seem to change the permissions to allow all users to have read/write access to the drives. The unit is automatically mounting the volumes as my user using the system, so other applications can not access the device. I want to set up a Plex Media Server to stream music, etc... but it will not scan the drives since it can not access them.

How can I change the permissions to allow everyone to read the volumes? IF I add them to the fstab as ntfs volumes, Ubuntu reports that they are not available during the boot up, likely due to the fire-wire not having found the drives yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not receive any feedback about my problem and the NTFS volumes.  However, I was able to work around this by simply making the Ubuntu user that logs in to be the plex user.  This way, when the drives are mounted as the default system user, the plex user has permission.  I simply reinstalled Ubuntu on this computer with a simple install and small footprint for my media server installation.

Not sure if this will work for others with a similar problem, but it did get me around my problem for now.